# matching binary data against hex value in go

Tags: go

I am trying to implement a simple parser in Go for the sancov file format https://clang.llvm.org/docs/SanitizerCoverage.html#sancov-data-format

the format is basically first 8 bytes is a magic value either 0xC0BFFFFFFFFFFF64 or 0xC0BFFFFFFFFFFF32 with the last byte of the magic value determining the size of the remaining offsets.

however i don't know how to compare a hex value to the byte value in Go for example

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    path := "test.exe.16900.sancov"

    f, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error while opening file", err)
    }

    for {
        data := make([]byte, 8)
        // ignoring errors for now
        bytesread, _ := f.Read(data)
        if bytesread == 0 {
            break
        }
        fmt.Printf("value: %x read %d bytes\n", data, bytesread)

        //"64ffffffffffbfc0"
        if data == 0xC0BFFFFFFFFFFF64 { // this is not valid 
            fmt.Println("64 bit header found")
        }

    }
}
```

what am i missing here?

the output (when removing the last if statement) is as follows

```
PS C:\Users\user\src\test> go run main.go
value: 64ffffffffffbfc0 read 8 bytes
value: 3b10004001000000 read 8 bytes
value: 7c10004001000000 read 8 bytes
```

Comment: Why do you want to compare against the hex encoding? Compare the bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare the data read from the file to a `[]byte` containing the magic value.

Declare a package-level variable with the magic value:

```
 var magicValue = []byte{0x64,0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xbf, 0xc0}
```

Compare with [bytes.Equal](https://godoc.org/bytes#Equal):

```
 data := make([]byte, len(magicValue))
 _, err := io.ReadFull(f, data)
 if err != nil {
     // handle error
 }
 if bytes.Equal(data, magicValue) { 
      fmt.Println("64 bit header found")
}
```

Use [io.ReadFull](https://godoc.org/io#ReadFull) to ensure that 8 bytes of data is read.

Answer (score 0):

You could compare the arrays:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "bytes"
)

var magicNumber = []byte{0x64, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xbf, 0xc0}

func main() {
    path := "test.exe.16900.sancov"

    f, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error while opening file", err)
    }

    data := make([]byte, len(magicNumber))
    if _, err := io.ReadFull(f, data); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", data)

    if bytes.Equal(data, magicNumber) {
        fmt.Println("header found")
    }
}
```

Comment: that  results in the following error:
    invalid operation: data == magic_number (mismatched types []byte and [32]byte)

Comment: i dont understand

Comment: still doesn't work. I added a print statement for header and magic_number to the output , this is the result with your changes (no match)  value: 64ffffffffffbfc0 read 8 bytes
 header -> 64ffffffffffbfc00000000000000000 magic_number -> 36346666666666666666666662666330
value: 3b10004001000000 read 8 bytes
 header -> 3b100040010000000000000000000000 magic_number -> 36346666666666666666666662666330
value: 7c10004001000000 read 8 bytes
 header -> 7c100040010000000000000000000000 magic_number -> 36346666666666666666666662666330